# Issue with linear gradient on svg text

Tags: css, svg, css-gradients

I am trying to put a linear gradient on svg text, but I'm not sure how to specify the fill color in the text class.  While learning how to do this, I found an example on the web so I'm using that, but where I specify fill color for the text (in the sfp2 class defined below), I put fill="url(#MyGradient)" x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"/> but the text no longer shows up on screen at all.

```
<div class="logo">
<svg viewBox="0 0 240 220" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<defs>
    <linearGradient id="MyGradient">
        <stop offset="5%"  stop-color="green"/>
        <stop offset="95%" stop-color="gold"/>
    </linearGradient>
</defs>

  <style>

    .sfp2 {
        font-family: CamphorW01-Regular, sans-serif;
        font-size: 7px;
        /*fill: rgb(71,164,71);*/
        fill="url(#MyGradient)" x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"/>
}

    .sfp9 {
        font-family: CamphorW01-Thin, sans-serif;
        font-size: 25px;
        fill: rgb(117,163,126);
        kerning="40";
    }

  </style>

  <text x="0" y="25" class="sfp9" kerning="40">MainLogo</text>
  <text x="24" y="33" class="sfp2">Tag Line</text>

</svg>
</div>
```

My questions are:  what am I doing wrong in the sfp2 class, and can we use linear-gradient instead when it's svg text?

Comment: I see letters just fine... Do not see the problem?

Comment: I have two different monitors, and I don't see text on either.  If I use fill: rgb(71,164,71) in the class def I can see text, but not with the gradient code.

Comment: The body background color is black; when I switch it to white I see the text, but no gradient.

Comment: Are those typo ( `fill=...` style in CSS ) or just mistaken concept by the author?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this:

```html
<div class="logo">
<svg viewBox="0 0 240 220" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<defs>
    <linearGradient id="MyGradient">
        <stop offset="5%"  stop-color="green"/>
        <stop offset="95%" stop-color="gold"/>
    </linearGradient>
</defs>

  <style>

    .sfp2 {
        font-family: CamphorW01-Regular, sans-serif;
        font-size: 7px;
        /*fill: rgb(71,164,71);*/
        fill:url(#MyGradient);
}

    .sfp9 {
        font-family: CamphorW01-Thin, sans-serif;
        font-size: 25px;
        fill: rgb(117,163,126);
        kerning="40";
    }

  </style>

  <text x="0" y="25" class="sfp9" kerning="40">MainLogo</text>
  <text id="test"  x="24" y="33" class="sfp2">Tag Line</text>

</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, here is what makes it work:  <text width="24" height="33" fill="url(#MyGradient)" x="24" y="33" width="33" height="24" class="sfp2">Tag Line</text>.  Thanks very much.

Comment: The preamble to this answer is totally irrelevant.  This answer works because it now has a valid `fill` rule in the CSS.  The one in the OPs original example is invalid because it has extra content (the ` x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"` part).  Also, The `<linearGradient>` element does not have `x` and `y` attributes.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau  I agree. I've edited my answer to remove the error.